# How to use Cyber Duck CLI with a custom end point url

Tags: cyberduck

I am trying to use Cyberduck CLI to connect to an S3 compatible S3-compatible CEPH API by UKFast (https://www.ukfast.co.uk/cloud-storage.html). It has the same function as Amazon but uses a different url/ server obviously. The connection is via secret key and pass phrase the same as S3. Cyberduck CLI protocols are listed here: https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/cli

I have tried using the below command the windows command prompt. The problem is that Cyberduck auto adds amazon AWS URL. So how do I use all the S3 options with a custom end point?

```
C:\> duck --list  s3://< Host >/  -i < AccessKey > -p < Secret Key>
```

Comment: Cyberduck is spelled in one word with no camel case.

Answer (score 5):

The `s3://` scheme is reserved for AWS in Cyberduck CLI. If you want to connect to a third party services compatible with the S3 protocol you will need to create a custom [connection profile](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/connection#ConnectionProfiles). A connection is a XML property list `.cyberduckprofile` file that you [install](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/cli#Profiles), providing another connection scheme. An example of such a profile is the Rackspace profile shipped within the application bundle in `Profiles/Rackspace US.cyberduckprofile` adding the `rackspace://` scheme to connect to [OpenStack Swift](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/openstack) compatible Rackspace Cloud. You can download one of the [other S3 profiles available](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/s3#Third-PartyS3providers) and use it as a template. Make sure to change at least the `Vendor` key to the protocol scheme you want to use such as `ukfast` and put in the service endpoint of *UKFast* as the value for the `Default Hostname` key (Which corresponds to `s3.amazonaws.com`; I cannot find any documentation for the S3 endpoint of *UKFast*.

When done, verify the new protocol is listed in `duck --help`. You can then use the command

`duck --list  ukfast://bucket/ --username <AccessKey> --password <Secret Key>`

to list files in a bucket.

You might also want to request *UKFast* to provide such a profile file for you and other users to make setup simpler. The same connection profile can also be used with [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io).